# Start java application with admin rights on startup in windows

Tags: java, autostart, admin-rights

I tried many ways to start a java program at startup with admin rights but it will not run. Basically, I wanted to make a remote desktop application in java and start the server side automatically at the system startup. I successfully done it with registry method and the app works fine except whenever an application which requires admin rights to work with like Task manager open up on the remote machine it will not gives access to remotely. One solution is to give admin privileges to my java server application but if I give this permission, the app will not run at startup anymore. I am using below code for start application on boot.

```
String value = currentPath+" /onboot";
String regPath = "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run";               
WinRegistry.writeStringValue(WinRegistry.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, regPath,"ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin", value);
```

So, How can I start a java application on start with admin rights?

Comment: One can wrap a java application as a Windows **service**. If that is what you want, an internet search will provide a how-to.

Comment: Thanks Joop Eggen. I already tried it but windows always stop my service after some time a quick search shows that windows stop a service if it will not do any task and in my case, the application waits for the connection.

Comment: Giving admin rights to java is a huge mistake and should be discouraged at all cost. Java has known vulnerabilities and if someone was able to exploit those vulnerabilities that person now has admin rights to your machine. The solution is to create a user and give it only the permissions it needs to perform its tasks and then run the java application as that user.